# Master equation of the Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I try to solve the master equation for the Poisson process. For this I have to check that
$$P_{ik}(t)=0 \;\;\forall t \geq0, \;\;\text{when }k<i $$
The explanation is given as follow:
$$\frac{dP_{i0}(t)}{dt}=-\lambda P_{i0}(t)$$
with $P_{i0}(0)=0$, if $i \neq 0$. Hence we can conclude $P_{i0}(t)=0$, $\forall t \geq 0$.
Why is this the case that we conclude that? It should be verry trivial but I can't see it... Many thanks for some help!